# Using Saxon, how do I include a compiled stylesheet (sep) in a separate stylesheet (xsl)?

Tags: xml, xslt, saxon, saxon-js

I'm compiling stylesheets (XSL) for use with the SaxonJS into their compiled form (SEP).

```
$ java -jar saxon9ee.jar -target:JS -xsl:child.xsl -export:child.sef.xml -nogo
```

I would like to use the compiled child stylesheet in another parent stylesheet via an include.

```
<xsl:include href="child.sef.xml"/>
```

But when I compile the parent stylesheet, I get errors.

```
$ java -jar saxon9ee.jar -target:JS -xsl:parent.xsl -export:parent.sef.xml -nogo
Static error at package on line 2 column 352 of child.sef.xml:
  XTSE0150: The supplied file does not appear to be a stylesheet
Errors were reported during stylesheet compilation
```

I do not want to have to deliver the child.xsl to the team composing the parent.xsl, only the compiled version, child.sep.xml.

Comment: Have you considered to convert the child.xsl into a package that you use with `xsl:use-package` in the `parent.xsl`?

Comment: @MartinHonnen - That is the same advice that I got from Michael Kay on the Saxonica forum earlier today.  I've never explored how to make packages before.  Do you know of a good XSLT 3.0 tutorial resource so that I can learn?

Comment: I am afraid there is not much about this available yet (well, I don't know whether the Pluralsight course https://www.pluralsight.com/courses/xslt-3-0-whats-new-part1 has been updated to cover the finalized spec of this year). The spec talks you through an example though with https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#packages-csv-library-example.